# Close magento 2 minicart on click

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

Using Magento2 commercial theme, and this theme has Minicart closing on "hover". We want to change this to original Magento2 closing on click.

Tried everything nothing works:

```
<div class="block block-minicart empty"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                 "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": false,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
        <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
```

Comment: Change Hover js to click

Comment: Where? i have changed minicart.phtml but no luck

Comment: can you please in question i will check

Comment: have you tried changing these values to true  `closeOnMouseLeave` and `closeOnEscape`

Comment: Yes i did but no luck

Comment: i updated the code and try in local it is worked. if it is not work please let me know what is the theme you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi  I tried like that it is work.

```
<div class="block block-minicart empty"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
```

Comment: set "triggerEvent":"click"

Comment: Nope not working, i have copied your code but no luck

Comment: i will check this what Magento given http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_dialog.html

Comment: $('.container').hover(function () { check also change click

Comment: This is what i have now: 

<div class="block block-minicart empty"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "triggerEvent":"click",
                "timeout": "500",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": false,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>

where is 
 
$('.container').hover(function () {?

Comment: templates\cart\minicart.phtml file

Comment: There is no such code
 
'$('.container').hover(function () { ' code in phtml file

Comment: you can add updated code at bottom of minicart.phtml and try

Comment: Added, cleard cache again and again but not working !

Comment: i think children is not get any data. i change to find now. please check comments.

Comment: Oke thank you, i will keep an eye on it. But no luck yet

Comment: i will check more and come back

Comment: Hi Rama,  any idea? i'm stuck here wit this problem lol.

Comment: Welcome back. What theme you are using. i am using luma it is worked.

Comment: Thank you, its a Luma theme but with commercial skin on it. See here http://dammekunststoffen.skyberatedev.nl/over-ons.html

Comment: i checked the problem is not from magento theme it is from css

Comment: http://dammekunststoffen.skyberatedev.nl/pub/static/version1499265098/frontend/Ortho/honourAuto/nl_NL/css/custom-theme.css in this theme replace css 

 .minicart-wrapper:hover  .block-minicart { 
 top: 73px;
 visibility: visible;
}

Comment: if it is work please accept answer

Comment: It is worked for you?

Comment: Goodmorning, sorry for my late reaction i had 3 days off. But Thank you very much it working man:) im very happy . Thanks again!